# Change empty string to zero in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list:

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
```

Some of these values are empty strings. I want to change all the empty strings to "0". Is there a 1 line linq command I can use to do that?

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget the `ToString()` on `field` if `ItemArray` doesn't contain strings.

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => 
    string.IsNullOrWhitespace(field.ToString()) ? "0" : field.ToString());
```

Comment: `field` may not be a string.

Comment: @recursive ha, was just fixing that.

Comment: The field.ToString() inside IsNUllOrWhitespace() did it. Was getting an error and wondering why but that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = 
    from field in row.ItemArray
    let s = field.ToString()
    select string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "0" : s;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => string.IsNullOrEmpty(field) ? "0" : field.ToString());
```

Comment: `field` may not be a string.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
fields.Select(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "0" : s);
```

Comment: `s` is probably not actually a string.

Comment: `s` is a string because `fields` type is IEnumerable<String>

Comment: That just means you need to *return* a string, not that you *start out* with one; the original code uses `ToString` in order to have a string to return.

Comment: you are mistaking `fields` and `row.ItemArray`